# How do I dynamically generate edit form for a selected item in a list using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm probably being such a noobie right now, but here's the question. I have a list of users generated by knockoutjs. Here's a basic code I'm using (all the unnecessary details skipped):

```
function User(info) {
    this.id = info.id;
    this.firstName = ko.observable(info.firstname);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(info.surname);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
}

function HrManagementViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("/users", function (data) {
        var mappedUsers = $.map(data, function (item) { return new User(item); });
        self.users(mappedUsers);
    });
}
```

And HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
   <li data-bind="text: fullName"></li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is whenever list item is clicked, editing form shows up prepopulated with clicked user's information. Any tips or tricks on how to accomplish this would be super awesome of you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ko.applyBindings()` function has an optional second argument, which can be used to specify the element you want to search for data-bind attributes. So you can make something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
    <li data-bind="text: fullName, click: $parent.showForm"></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<form id="form">
    <p><input data-bind="value: id"></input></p>
    <p><input data-bind="value: firstName"></input></p>
    <p><input data-bind="value: lastName"></input></p>
</form>
```

Then, in HrManagementViewModel:

```
self.currentUser = ko.observable(null);

self.showForm = function(user, event) {
    // first argument here is the item, associated with the <li> element
    // second - the event object.

    var previousSelection = self.selectedUser();
    self.selectedUser(user); // Wrap your user viewModel in observable. To change
                             // the input fields bindings just update it 
                             // with a new viewModel and KO will do the rest.
    if (previousSelection == null) {
        var target = document.getElementById('form');
        ko.applyBindings(self.selectedUser, target); 
    }
}
```

Here, give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/mH3fx/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mH3fx/ is a bit bugged though. When you try to edit the information in the input fields, the lastname/firstname is being assigned to ALL users instead of one. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's because multiple bindings got applied to the same input fields. I remember using ko.cleanNode(element) to unbind elements before applying the new bindings, but for some reason I couldn't make it work in the jsfiddle. I've updated my answer with a little work-around that will help.